# How to add a background image to a plot created using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created this line chart using D3.

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369

Suppose I need to add some .png image from the local file on my computer to the above graph,  how can I do that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `background` property through CSS to `svg` element as any other HTML tag. For example, like this you will have google logo on background:

```
svg {
  background: url('https://www.google.nl/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') no-repeat;
}
```

More on properties you can use in [background, w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)

Comment: Try this way. `svg.style("background","url('https://www.google.nl/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') no-repeat");`

Comment: @Gilsha thank you so much, how can I do the same  for a local png file?

`svg {
        background: url('file:///YourCom/User/Desktop/D3DEMO/blue_pebble.jpg') no-repeat;
    }`

is not working

Comment: Are you able to get the image when you open the same url in a new tab?

Comment: @Artiga - open new tab (Chrome) press Ctrl/Cmd + O, open image file in browser - then you can copy the full url path to image and paste in svg.style {}

Comment: @Gilsha, yes I am able to open it.

Comment: @shershen, I did exactly what you asked me to but I am getting  `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/iM/Desktop/D3DEMO/beautiful_backgrounds_hd.png`

Comment: Seems like your image file is at the same location. Try by giving the image file name only. googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png